# Why am I not seeing a stack trace with 'throw new Error'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why am I getting the following error with this simple code below when testing on a node server?

```
code/app2/i.js:35
        throw new Error("here")
              ^
Error: here
```

I'm actually expecting to see a stack trace [as per the book 'Smashing node.js'](http://www.aod.zyklon-b.tk/library/web-development/%7BEN%7D_%5BRauch%5D_Smashing_Node.js.pdf) ([picture of the relevant page 35](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axveZ.png)):

```
* node uncaught-http-js

/uncaught-http.js:4
  throw new Error("here");
        ^
Error: This will be uncaught
    at Server.<anonymous> (/uncaught-http.js:4:9)
    at Server.emit(events.js:70:17)
    at HttpParser.onIncoming(http.js:1514:12)
    at HttpParser.onHeadersComplete(http.js:102:31)
    at Socket.andata (http.js:1410:22)
    at TCP.onread(net.js:354:27)
```

but that's not happening.

Here's the code.

```
function c () {
    b();
};
function b () {
    a();
};

function a () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        throw new Error('here');
    }, 10);
};

c();
```

Comment: Because you are throwing an Error?! Or are you asking something else?

Comment: You are getting a js error because `throw new Error('here')` explicitly tells javascript to output an error message. Your question is basically the equivalent of "I have `alert('hi!')`, why is this code showing an alert box?!?"

Comment: Unhandled exceptions display an error to the node.js console.  That's how they work.  When you execute `throw`, you are creating an exception and since you don't have any `try/catch` block to catch that exception, it becomes an unhandled exception.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with how you throw the error. It throws the expected error (“here”). It doesn’t matter where the position is; the `new` operator is correct.

Comment: Funfact: replace setTimeout with setInterval and see how it does not stop the execution and keeps on throwing error :)

Comment: For the record, @AgentZebra, i'm pretty sure the 2 lines above the line `Error: here` **is the stacktrace**

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you. In the book the stack trace is much longer, hence the confusion.

Comment: @aify maybe it's just me being a naive Python-acquainted person but I would expect a stack trace to, yknow, *trace the call stack,* and not just give me the one line where the exception is thrown. Where are the lines about `i.js:40` calling `c` calling `b` calling `a`?

Comment: @badp Possibly (probably?) omitted, I'd guess.

Comment: @TomMedley I see you also missed `setTimeout`? :)

Comment: @badp in JS you need to catch and use e.stack() to get that entire fancy trace you're looking for. The default sometimes is tiny and just tells you exactly where the error is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't see the whole stack trace because you throw an error in A() **asynchronously** (using setTimeout). If you throw it synchronously - you'll see the trace c()->b()->a().

Try it: http://jsbin.com/yirorimewe/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Sounds to me like this should be the accepted answer then.

Answer (score 6):

This is what your code does:
It calls method 'c', which calls method 'b', which calls method 'a', which throws an error (inside method 'a' there is a throw error statement).

What you've posted *is* the stack trace (it shows you the line in the file where the error occurred).

Comment: According to the book 'Smashing Node.Js' this should give me a stack trace, but it doesn't. Maybe this is where my confusion came from. Thanks tho, that helped.

Comment: @AgentZebra: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask If the output isn't what you expect, then problems should contain the expected output and the actual output so that we can provide effective feedback.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @MooingDuck , expected output is in a screenshot, how do I include that here?

Comment: @AgentZebra When editing the question, there should be a button for attaching an image file.  Realistically, textual output is preferred when possible.

Answer (score -4):

The function is displaying the output. Throw new Error.